# No Storage account for VM Disks in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azure-managed-disk

According to Microsoft documentation. there are managed disks and unmanaged disks. Managed disks are something managed by microsoft. All the VHDs are stored as page blob in storage account.
Question: When I create a linux VM with additional disk I don't see storage account created in resources list.   I dont see storage account created when VMs are created for both OS disk and Data disk. I really appreciate if some one answer this.

Storage account and VM Disks are 2 separate things ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these disks managed or unmanaged?

Comment: They are managed disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Storage Account and Page Blob behind the scenes but they are kind of hidden from you. When the disks are `managed`, the necessary infrastructure is created and managed by Microsoft so that you don't have to worry about them.

This is the reason you don't see any Storage Account and Page Blobs in your Azure Subscription for managed disks. You will see them only when your disks are `unmanaged` as then you are responsible for the management of these resources.

Please see this link for a nice comparison between managed and unmanaged disks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/3619/what-is-the-difference-between-managed-disk-and-un.html.